# Multiple file upload to database in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, file, file-upload

I'm trying to add multiple files to my database. When I try to do single upload it works well and there is a no problem with my encoder or coder which is based on my core layer.

It add those files well but it just adding same file all the time,let me show my code :

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostCategory(Category category, List<IFormFile> files)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int request;
            _unitOfWorkCat.RepositoryCategory.Create(category);
            request = HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;

            if (request == 200)
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Kategori ekleme işleminiz başarılı!";
                TempData["JS"] = "showSuccess();";
                _unitOfWorkCat.Complete();

                foreach (var a in files)
                {
                    var File = _fileUploader.FileUploadToDatabase(files);
                    var x = File.Result;
                    int ID = category.CategoryID;
                    x.CategoryID = ID;
                    _unitOfWorkFR.RepositoryFileRepo.Create(x);
                    _unitOfWorkFR.Complete();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Kategori ekleme işleminiz başarısız!";
                TempData["JS"] = "showError();";
            }

            return RedirectToAction("CategoryIndex");
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "Eklemek istediğiniz veri hatalı!";
            TempData["JS"] = "showError();";
            return RedirectToAction("CategoryIndex");
        }
}
```

I check it out my view, it sends the same count which I'm choosing. I want to add those files to my database and I don't want to add the same file each of it.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Where you wrote `var File = _fileUploader.FileUploadToDatabase(files);` I think what you really want is this `var File = _fileUploader.FileUploadToDatabase(a);`

Comment: its not accepting bc they are not the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve my problem with my recursive function.
Here its:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostCategory(Category category, List<IFormFile> files)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int request;
            _unitOfWorkCat.RepositoryCategory.Create(category);
            request = HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;

            if (request == 200)
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Kategori ekleme işleminiz başarılı!";
                TempData["JS"] = "showSuccess();";
                _unitOfWorkCat.Complete();

                int i = 0; int b = 1;
                    foreach (var a in files)
                    {
                       int count = files.Count;
                        if (i < count)
                        {
                            var fi = files.GetRange(i, b);
                            var File = _fileUploader.FileUploadToDatabase(fi);
                            var x = File.Result;
                            int ID = category.CategoryID;
                            x.CategoryID = ID;
                            _unitOfWorkFR.RepositoryFileRepo.Create(x);
                            _unitOfWorkFR.Complete();
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Kategori ekleme işleminiz başarısız!";
                TempData["JS"] = "showError();";
            }

            return RedirectToAction("CategoryIndex");
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "Eklemek istediğiniz veri hatalı!";
            TempData["JS"] = "showError();";
            return RedirectToAction("CategoryIndex");
        }
}
```

***Thanks anyway.***